# How can I calculate a matrix of dot products?

Tags: python, numpy

So, I have two three-dimensional arrays, both have `shape` of `(n, m, n)`. I want to calculate a 2d matrix (`(n, m)`) of the dot products of the vectors my arrays are comprised of. Something like this, but preferably vectorized:

```
res = np.zeros(a.shape[:-1])

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[0])):
        res[i][j] = a[i][j] @ b[i][j]
```

I've fiddled with both `dot` and `tensordot` for about an hour now, but can't figure this out at all!

Comment: What's wrong with `numpy.dot(a[i][j], b[i][j])`?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Well, it requires two nested loops, which does not look very performant to me

Comment: Well if your code works then you should specify in your question that you're looking for a more efficient method. And keep in mind that any numpy builtin probably has to use a double for loop anyway because double-vectorization works that way... not sure though

Comment: You could also try np.einsum.

Comment: If you only want to calculate the dot product along the last axis of both arrays `np.dot` does not work. It takes the last axis of one array and the second to last of the other one.
Instead you shoud use np.inner

Comment: If you reopen the question, I have a solution :)